# Babel-loader 8 complains about not finding deprecated babel-preset-es2015

Tags: babel-loader

with this webpack config:

```
  { test: /\.tsx?$/, 
    use:[
    {
      loader:'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets:['@babel/preset-env']
      }
    },
    {
      loader:'ts-loader'
    }]
  },
```

I get an error message `Error: Cannot find module 'babel-preset-es2015'`

If I add that module I get two errors

babel-preset-es2015 is deprecated, use babel-preset-env

But when I install babel-preset-env I still get error about not finding babel-preset-es2015

When I install babel-preset-es2015 I get the error

Error: Plugin/Preset files are not allowed to export objects, only functions. In /Users/henrikbechmann/Servers/tribalopolis/www/tribalopolis.com/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/lib/index.js

So it's a complete trap!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Answer: Mostly a matter of updating .babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    "@babel/env",
    "@babel/react"
  ]
}
```

and of course updating modules

tip: try npx update-babel